# Error that says Rscript is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: r, rscript

I'm currently in school working on R. I made a file in RStudio and I want to run one of the blocks I made. When I try to use Rscript in the command line, it says it's not recognized. I looked on other articles with similar issues and none of them work. I'm trying to use the following in the command line:

```
RScript --vanilla -e 'source("Example1.R")' -e 'print(Q1)'
```

before i run this, i make sure i'm in the right directory where the Example1.R file lives. I went into my control panel -> system -> advanced system settings -> Environment Variables -> and added C:\R\R-3.2.2\bin named "Rspath" under system variables.

So I'm really stuck at this point and don't know how to fix. I had a similar issue when I was trying to run python3 last semester and someone was able to help so fingers crossed again. Thanks for reading!!

Comment: You shouldn't add a new system variable whith the name Rspath. You should be editing the PATH system environment variable to also include the path to R. And that path should match the one you see when you run `R.home("bin")` in the R console. Are you really running R version 3.2.2? That's kind of an old version. You'll need to close and restart any command line windows before the new effects will take place.

Comment: this is so helpful thank you! When I run that in Rstudio, i get C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-41~1.2/bin/x64. is that what i should edit the PATH to be??